# Looping through a list to create a CSV for each customer in the list

Tags: excel, vba

I have some functioning code that takes a sheet from my workbook and saves it as a CSV, it looks like this:

```
Sub export_quote()

    Dim CSVBook As Workbook
    Set CSVBook = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Copy Before:=CSVBook.Sheets(1)
    CSVBook.SaveAs Filename:="G:\My Drive\X\Finished Estimates\" & Range("D4").Text & " " & "Quote" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    CSVBook.Close
End Sub
```

I am trying to convert it to make a separate CSV for each customer in a list (with that customer's name in cell E2).

I now have:

```
Sub export_quote()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("I15:I30")
    For Each cell In rng
        Dim CSVBook As Workbook
        Dim Str As String
        Dim wks1 As Worksheet
        Set Str = CStr(cell)
        Set CSVBook = Workbooks.Add
        Set wks1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote")
        wks1.Range(E2).Value = Str
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Copy Before:=CSVBook.Sheets(1)
        CSVBook.SaveAs Filename:="G:\My Drive\X\Finished Estimates\" & Range("D4").Text & " (" & Range("D2").Text & ") " & "Quote" & "(" & Str & ")" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        CSVBook.Close
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I have a feeling I'm pretty far off here, so my questions are:

1. Can I use cell to get the customers name into a string? If not, how do I get the customers name into the worksheet?
2. How do I set my loop to skip empty cells in my list?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use cell to get the customers name into a string? If not, how do
>   I get the customers name into the worksheet?

Yes, you can. You can set the value of a cell like this:

```
wks1.Range("E2").Value = Str
```

In your code, you are only missing the quotes around "E2"

You can get the value of a cell into a string variable like this:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim str As String

str = cell.Value
```

> How do I set my loop to skip empty cells in my list?

You can test if the cell is empty at the beginning of the loop like this:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range

For Each cell In Range
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then

        '// do stuff

    End If
Next Range
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will try this out tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
Sub Copy_To_Workbooks()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim foldername As String
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 1

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Set the file extension/format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 56 Then
            FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 56
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Delete the sheet RDBLogSheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("RDBLogSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Add worksheet to copy/Paste the unique list
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws2.Name = "RDBLogSheet"

    'Fill in the path\folder where you want the new folder with the files
    'you can use also this "C:\Users\Ron\test"
    MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'Create folder for the new files
    foldername = MyPath & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & "\"
    MkDir foldername

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add new workbook with one sheet
                Set WSNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

                'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With

                'Save the file in the new folder and close it
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                                    cell.Value & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1

                    WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                     "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & _
                      "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr & """)"

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = _
                    "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & cell.Value & FileExtStr & """)"
                End If

                WSNew.Parent.Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

            'Show all the data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Red cell: can't use the Unique name as file name"
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Created Files (Click on the link to open a file)"
        .Cells(3, "A").Value = "Unique Values"
        .Cells(3, "B").Value = "Full Path and File name"
        .Cells(3, "A").Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(3, "B").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    ws2.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

[image]